# Is the inflaton field baryon symmetric?

Tags: particle-physics, cosmological-inflation, baryogenesis

The theory states that after inflation ends, the energy stored in the inflaton field decays to produce particles.

Does the inflaton field have baryon number associated with it?
Is the field baryon symmetric and produce asymmetry after the decay?

Comment: It depends on the model. In some, yes. In others, no. We do not have much experimental data on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this review](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2018/reviews/rpp2018-rev-bbang-cosmology.pdf) :

> The production of a net baryon asymmetry requires baryon number violating
>   interactions,C and CP
>   violation and a departure from thermal equilibrium The
>   first two of these ingredients are expected to be contained in grand unified theories as
>   well as in the non-perturbative sector of the Standard Model, the third can be realized in an expanding universe where as we have seen interactions come in and out of equilibrium

There are proposals which place baryon asymmetry at the time of inflation, and in these the inflaton "decays" will generate the baryon asymmetry, [example](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0103348) .  :

> In this letter we explore the possibility of creating the baryon asymmetry of the universe during inflation and reheating due to the decay of a field associated with the inflaton. CP violation is attained by assuming that this field is complex with a phase that varies as the inflaton evolves. We consider chaotic and natural inflation scenarios. In the former case, the complex decaying field is the inflaton itself and, in the latter case, the phase of the complex field is the inflaton. We calculate the asymmetry produced using the Bogolyubov formalism that relates annihilation and creation operators at late time to the annihilation and creation operators at early time.

It is probably possible to build up a theory where the inflaton itself carries baryon violating properties. It is an open field of research. There is as yet no standard model for this.

Comment: There are  models where the inflaton decays into baryons and the asymmetry is built in the decay, and there are other models where the inflaton decays in a baryon symmetric way and CP violation happens through other mechanisms. **It is model dependent and a point of research**.

Comment: *”In models where the inflaton decays into baryons”*  Does it mean that in these models,  the inflaton field possesses baryon asymmetry property even *before* reheating occurs?

Comment: One would have to read the particular model. In the excerpt of the abstract in the example above it talks about a process, a mechanism that will define the baryon number. the process generates the asymmetry.